# FadeInImage error while using in ListView

Tags: android, flutter, dart

```
setState() called after dispose(): _ImageState#46191(lifecycle state: defunct, not mounted, stream: ImageStream#75f5c(MultiFrameImageStreamCompleter#f16d5, [250×130] @ 1.0x, 2 listeners), pixels: null, loadingProgress: null, frameNumber: null, wasSynchronouslyLoaded: false)


This error happens if you call setState() on a State object for a widget that no longer appears in the widget tree (e.g., whose parent widget no longer includes the widget in its build). This error can occur when code calls setState() from a timer or an animation callback.

The preferred solution is to cancel the timer or stop listening to the animation in the dispose() callback. Another solution is to check the "mounted" property of this object before calling setState() to ensure the object is still in the tree.
This error might indicate a memory leak if setState() is being called because another object is retaining a reference to this State object after it has been removed from the tree. To avoid memory leaks, consider breaking the reference to this object during dispose(). >>> #0      State.setState.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1197:9)
```

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.17.5, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19041.388], locale en-IN)
    • Flutter version 1.17.5 at F:\FlutterProjects\FlutterSdk\flutter
    • Framework revision 8af6b2f038 (6 weeks ago), 2020-06-30 12:53:55 -0700
    • Engine revision ee76268252
    • Dart version 2.8.4


[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.0)
    • Android SDK at E:\sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.0
    • ANDROID_HOME = E:\sdk
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Android Studio (version 4.0)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin version 47.1.2
    • Dart plugin version 193.7361
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)

[!] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2019.2)
    • IntelliJ at C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.2.3
    X Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    X Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
    • For information about installing plugins, see
      https://flutter.dev/intellij-setup/#installing-the-plugins
```

I have 300+ images in `ArrayList`..
But I load to `ListView` in chuck of 20.

but whenever I filter list using some search query, I face this issue which lead to WHITE BACKGROUND instead of actual Image.

below is my code to load image

```
Container(
            width: double.infinity,
            child: FadeInImage.assetNetwork(
              placeholder: 'assets/loading_image.png',
              image: Util.getImageUrl(item.business_featured_image),
              height: 130,
              imageErrorBuilder:
                  (BuildContext context, Object y, StackTrace z) {                    
              return Image(
                  image: NetworkImage(
                      Util.getImageUrl(item?.business_featured_image)),
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  height: 130,
                  errorBuilder:
                      (BuildContext context, Object y, StackTrace z) {                       
                    return Center(
                        child: Icon(
                          Icons.broken_image,
                          size: 120,
                          color: colorLightGrey,
                        ));
                  },
                );
              },
              imageCacheHeight: 130,
              imageCacheWidth: 250,
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
          )
```

and I'm also checking mount and dispose property

```
if (!_isDispose && mounted) { setState(() { log("setState calling : "); mainList = value; }); _increasePageSize(); }
```

This bug ate mine 2 days already, please help with this.
Same bug is listed on Flutter Github account from last 2 years and still not fixed.

Comment: @Mobina can u help me with this please ?

Comment: Have you tried overriding the `setState` method in your `StateFulWidget`? `@override
   void setState(f) {
    if (mounted) {
      super.setState(f);
    }
  }`

Comment: @Mobina Some how I overcome from that issue by using CacheNetworkImage